# "Overrides deprecated method" on onCreateDialog

Tags: java, android

I have a class in which I'm trying to create a `Dialog` but when I put the method `onCreateDialog` it appears crossed by a line. It gives to me the following error message:

> Overrides deprecated method in 'android.app.Activity'.
>
> This inspection reports where deprecated method is used in the specified inspection scope.

But when I go to the official documentation of Android I didn't see that this method it's deprecated so I don't understand what happens: [onCreateDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html#onCreateDialog(android.os.Bundle))

My `onCreateDialog` code:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case 1:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month, day);
        case 2:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener, hour, minute,false);
    }

    return null;
}
```

But if I execute my application, it works properly so I have some **questions**:

- Why it let to me execute the application?
- How can I solve it?
- Is it bad that this message appears? I mean, could be a problem associated by it? Could it generate future problems?

Any help that helps me to clarify would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Activity.onCreateDialog()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateDialog(int)) is deprecated.

> This method was deprecated in API level 13.
>   Use the new DialogFragment class with FragmentManager instead; this is also available on older platforms through the Android compatibility package.

Deprecated code means it's use is discouraged and may not be supported going forward. That doesn't necessarily mean the code doesn't work; it may still run as before, but if changes are made that break this functionality, there's no guarantee anyone will fix it since they've already stated it should not be used.

To "fix" it, you should look at [`DialogFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) and how to use fragments in general, and show one of those instead.

Comment: My god! Just I was searching in the wrong `.onCreateDialog`. Thanks for the good explanation ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `This class was deprecated in API level 28.
Use the Support Library DialogFragment for consistent behavior across all devices and access to Lifecycle. ` New class; [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html)